# Javascript function scope discrepncy between chrome and firefox, which one is correct

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I see different behavior for the following Javascript code executed on Chrome and Firefox:

```
var outer = function (param) {
  var inner = function (theinput) {
    return theinput * 2;
  };
  return 'The result is ' + inner(param);
};

console.log(outer(2));

console.log(inner(5));

Result on Firefox:
"The result is 4"
10

Result on Chrome:
"The result is 4"
undefined
```

Since inner is declared as "var", I guess the output on Chrome is correct as the function "inner" acts as a private function. I think firefox implementation is incorrect.

If "var" was removed for inner, the inner function becomes promoted as global function after its first execution.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am using `Firefox 37.0.1` and my console output is the following: `The result is 4` `ReferenceError: inner is not defined`

Comment: do you have declared the `inner` function somewhere before?

Comment: First time I had ran with inner without var, soit ran the inner as a global scope and then ran the above code where inner is with var (i.e. private) function,then I see the issue. I am also using Fiefox 37.0.1.

Comment: I tested again after closing the Firefox browser and again running the above piece of code, at this point I see the result as: "The result is 4"
undefined.

Comment: I tested again after closing the Firefox browser and again running the above piece of code, at this point I see the result as: The result is 4 undefined. 
So, looks like once the function is run in global scope, it remains until the browser or console is shut down. Checked the same in all browsers seeing the same behavior now. Thanks everyone for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> Since inner is declared as "var", I guess the output on Chrome is correct as the function "inner" acts as a private function. I think firefox implementation is incorrect.

Neither is correct. Since `inner` is scoped inside the function assigned to `outer`, trying to access it from where you have `console.log(inner(5));` should throw a ReferenceError because it isn't declared.

**That** is the behaviour I get when [testing your code](http://jsbin.com/pavabutodi/1/) in both Firefox and Chrome.

[image]

> If "var" was removed for inner, the inner function becomes promoted as global function after its first execution.Is my understanding correct?

Yes (unless you were running the code in strict mode, in which case you would get an error when you tried to assign a value to `inner` since you wouldn't have `var inner` anywhere).

Comment: Me too. Something might be wrong in OPs environment. Maybe he ran the experiment without `var` before.